# How to limit the range of ports that QTcpServer is using for listening?

Tags: c++, qt

I have an application that uses QTcpServer to listen for incoming connections. There are actually multiple processes running simultaneously, so i just do:

```
QTcpServer *server = new QTcpServer;
server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 0);
```

and if that succeeds, i just ask the server about the port that it's listening to. Since the port is chosen automatically, now I need to limit it's range. For example, I want it to automatically choose a port between 25000 and 26000. Is there a good way I can do it, or should i just keep trying to listen to any of the ports in the range, and until I succeed to keep changing the port? It is a solution, but a brute-force one. So, if there's a better way, I would really like to know.

Thanks

Comment: If you listen to port 0, it's the same as an ephemeral port.  So it'll choose a "random" port within a range that *varies - depending on the OS.  If you want to choose a port between 25000 and 26000 then generate a random number between that range.  How are you coordinating the port number with the client that will be connecting?  The burden of a look-up is normally on the client that's connecting - but there are other schemes, much like regular FTP (passive vs active mode).

Comment: The coordination of the port number with the client is done by other process that's communicating with the one in question. So, that's not a problem. I was just wondering if there's some more elegant solution to the problem, or some api that I missed.

Comment: I'm confused about your question, "__should i just keep trying to listen to any of the ports in the range__".  Listening (i think you mean connecting though) to all of the ports and as you put it, in a brute-force manner, sounds crazy to me - so maybe I missed something and that's primarily why I asked about the coordination of the port between server and client.  Agreeing on a port would avoid having to try all connections to ports within a known range such as 25k - 26k.